# Scrolling interface CSS- Change color on Black Background

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make the scrolling item change to white or light grey color when it is on black?

For problem see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhlvk691tahsf8h/Screenshot%202015-02-15%2016.25.47.png?dl=0

Edit: someone had removed my picture
The HTML is

```
    <!-- TO TOP-SCROLLING --> 
    <a href="javascript:;" class="scrollToTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a> 
    <!-- END OF TO TOP-SCROLLING -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the context of the question as the image link does not work for me but I imagine the 'scrolling item' could have a class applied when it begins scrolling. Remove the class when it stops.

Then using CSS apply a different background-color when the scrolling class is applied.

Comment: Sorry, someone had removed my picture. Can you please give me a concrete example? I have added my HTML.